# "Парфумер" чи "парфюмер"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, калька

В Академічному словнику вказано, що правильно - парфюмерія, то чому ж твір Зюскінда називається "ПарфУмер", а не "ПарфЮмер"?

[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumerija)

> *ПАРФЮМЕ́РІЯ*, ї, жін.
>
> 1. збірн. Косметичні вироби (духи, одеколон і т. ін.), звичайно ароматичні. Вона наповнила кімнату м'якістю хутра й різким запахом парфюмерії (Любомир Дмитерко, Розлука, 1957, 18).

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BA_%D0%97%D1%8E%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4)

> Екранізація творів у кіно
> *Парфумер* — IMDb: «Perfume: The Story of a Murderer», 2006
> Твори
> *Парфуми* (Das Parfum — нім. Дух, Запах, Аромат)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За сучасним правописом ([«Правопис», 2015, § 90.6](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90p6)) має бути через «-у-»:

> У словах, запозичених із французької мови, після шиплячих *ж*, *ш* пишеться відповідно до французького *u* українське *у*, а не *ю*: *брошу́ра*, *журі́*, *парашу́т*; також у словах *парфу́ми*, *парфуме́рія*.

Найімовірніше, написання «[парфю́мер](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumer)», «[-ія](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumerija)», «[-ний](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumernyj)» зі «Словника української мови» в 11 томах 1970-х років відповідало старішому правипису. Іноді в електроних версіях цього словника пишуть щось на зразок «це написання застаріле, за сучасним правописом мало б бути так-то», але навряд чи вони роблять це для кожного слова (в них навіть нові одруки порівняно з паперовою версією іноді трапляються). Взагалі, у тому словнику дивна картина: «[парфу́ми](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfumy)» — «[парфу́мити](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfumyty)» — «[парфу́мний](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfumnyj)», але «[парфюме́р](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumer)» — «[парфюме́рія](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumerija)» — «[парфюме́рний](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumernyj)» — «[парфюме́рник](http://sum.in.ua/s/parfjumernyk)» (мабуть, тоді писали «-у-» в цьому випадку лише під наголосом).

Сучасний орфографічний словник [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) 2008 року містить здебільшого варіанти на «-у-» (хіба що «парфуме́рник»/«парфюме́рник» у двох варіантах, але це може бути й одрук; а «парфуме́р» лише з «-у-»).

«Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» В. Бусела 2000-х років (опублікований зокрема [як «The Comprehensive Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language» на сайті «ABBYY Lingvo Live»](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) і [на сайті «Словопедія»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/935149.html)) теж пише через «-у-».

«Словник української мови» в 20 томах 2010-х років ще не видав тому на «п-», але містить «парфумерн-» через «-у-» (на відміну від старого в 11 томах, який мав через «-ю-») в цитатах до інших статей:

> <sub>[ВАНІ́ЛЬ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6594&page=241) <…> *Ваніль використовується у харчовій, парфумерній та фармацевтичній промисловості* (із журн.)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[ЖИРОПІ́Т](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=27089&page=918) <…>  *Складникі [sic] жиропоту являють собою досить цінну сировину, яка широко використовується в парфумерній та медичній промисловостях* (з наук.-попул. літ.).</sub>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[ЖОНКІ́ЛЬ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=915&wordid=174912) <…> *Тонкий аромат жонкілі надає шарму будь-якій парфумерній композиції* (з газ.).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Доповнє проблематіку [відповідї](/a/3248/585) пана [@Sasha](/users/4/sasha)*</sup>

Для порівняння правопис 1928

> #### [§ 67](https://r2u.org.ua/node/244)
>
> Французьке *u* та німецьке *ü* передаємо через **ю**: [*Бельв**ю́***](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B2%27%D1%8E%22), [*б**ю**ро́*](https://www.google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B1%27%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%BE%22), *б**ю**дже́т*, *б**ю**ст*, *вестиб**ю́**ль*, [*ж**ю**рі́*](/questions/2979/), *куп**ю́**ра*, *мен**ю́***, *нокт**ю́**рн*, *н**ю**а́нс*, *уверт**ю́**ра*, [*Ж**ю**ль Верн*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD), *б**ю́**рґер*, *Д**ю́**рінґ*, *Д**ю**ссельдорф*, *Л**ю**бек*, *М**ю**нцер*, [*Ш**ю**ц*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D0%A8%D1%8E%D1%86) і т. ін.

Панї запитувачка може помітити тут декілька „складних“ слів. **Основна причина:** не дуже питомі помʼякшення, особливо для **ф**, який не має парного дзвінкого звуку, а наближений **в** не охочий до помʼякшення. Хоч инколи таки: трохи помʼякшується *с**в**ято*; наближається до цього *збіж**ж**я*, *облич**ч**я*. Цьому підтверджує і наступний § про апостроф:

> #### [§ 68](//r2u.org.ua/node/245)
>
> Апостроф у чужих словах пишеться:
>
> **1.** Після приголосних **б**, **п**, **в**, **м**, **ф**, **г**, **ґ**, **к**, **х**, **р**, **ж**, **ч**, **ш** перед йотованими голосними: *мар’я́ж*, *суб’є́кт*, *об’є́кт*, *Барб’є́*, *Жюр’є́н де ля Ґрав’є́р*, *К’ю*, *Руж’є́*, *Клов’є́*, *В’єн*, *П’ємо́нт*, *Б’юкенен* і т. ін. (але не після **н**, **д**, **т**, **л**, **з**, **с**, **ц** — див. § 69).

Порівняйте з чинним:

> #### [§ 92. Апостроф](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par92)
>
> **1.** Апостроф у словах іншомовного походження та похідних від них пишеться перед **я**, **ю**, **є**, **ї**:
>
> **а)** після приголосних **б**, **п**, **в**, **м**, **ф**, **г**, **к**, **х**, **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **р**: *б’єф*, *комп’ютер*, *п’єдестал*, *інтерв’ю*, *прем’єр*, *торф’яний*, *к’янті*, *миш’як*, *кар’єра*; *П’ємонт*, *П’яченца*, *Рив’єра*, *Ак’яб*, *Іх’ямас*; *Барб’є*, *Б’єрнсон*, *Б’юкенен*, *Женев’єва*, *Ф’єзоле*, *Монтеск’є*, *Руж’є*, *Фур’є*;
>
> **б)** після кінцевого приголосного префікса: *ад’юнкт*, *ад’ютант*, *ін’єкція*, *кон’юнктура*.

І відоме проблемне [правило девʼятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), де чужеслово не помʼякшується через **і** з **д**, **т**, **з**, **с**, **ц**, **ж**, **ш**, **ч**, **р**.

Comment: Але це змінилося не в 1930-х. Адже ще в 1970-х нормативним було «парфюме́р» — «парфюме́рія» — «парфюме́рний» — «парфюме́рник» («парфу́ми» — «парфу́мити» — «парфу́мний»). А вже (припускаю) у 1990-х зробили все через «-у-».